# Field is Editable but profile and layout show Read-Only

Tags: case, page-layout

Trying to make Case Owner un-editable but no matter what I do it still shows up as having the edit button? This page layout pictured in the screenshots is the correct one.

[image: Read-only]

[image: But editable?]

Comment: I'm guessing that the profile you're looking at has Modify All Data or Case: Modify All Data. Try checking a profile without these permissions.

Comment: @sfdcfox that is not the case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You cannot make `Case Owner` field read only, from your field level security.

Just navigate to 'Case Owner' field and click on `Set Field Level Security` button. You will see read only checkboxes are disabled.

Though you try to assign Read-only from Page Layout, it will still show up.

If you have Edit permission on that object you will still edit Case Owner field.

**Workaround**

*Approach 1*

Write a validation rule and restrict if user of specific profile try to change the Case owner.

*Approach 2*

Create a formula field which will show Case Owner Hyperlink type.

Create a separate page layout for those profiles and remove original Case Owner field from this layout and put this custom case owner field on this layout.

Comment: Thanks Santanu. So you're saying no matter what, in Field Level Security setting Case Owner to Read-Only is disabled? Is that baked into Salesforce? Or am I not... admin enough to do it?

Comment: This is the way Salesforce created this. thats why I have mentioned workarounds. If you are fine with my ans then accept this, so other members can find this useful

Comment: @SantanuBoral You can make owner on other objects and it works, or at least it used to. I wonder if this is a new feature/bug?

Comment: @sfdcfox same thing is happening for like Account and other Custom objects also

Comment: @SantanuBoral was it always this way or is this recent?